# The Repository Pattern , refactoring code

Tags: development, patterns-and-practices, design-patterns

I'm trying to develop simple sharepoint application using  the repository pattern.Application should return employee informations from `SPList` based on some queries and than show them into HTML table(I've used repeater control).

I've followed repository pattern instructions and created list repository , first I've created class `EmployeeInfo` where I've mapped columns form SP List and than class `CAMLQueryBuilder` where I've stored strings that are representing CAML queries.

Also I've created `SharePointConnector` class , and there are some of methods like `GetCurrentUserName` etc, and the most relevant one is `public List<Models.EmployeeInfo> GetEmployeeInfo(SPListItemCollection splic)` which is taking `SPListItemCollection` as parametar , and returns list of employees infos that is later bind as data source to `repeater`.

Then I've created class :

```
 public class PhoneNumbers
{
    public PhoneNumbers()
    {
    }

    private static SPListItemCollection GetPhoneNumbers(string queryString)
    {
        using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite(Models.Sol.SiteName))
        {
            using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList myList = currentWeb.Lists[Models.Sol.PB1.ListName];
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                query.Query = queryString;
                return myList.GetItems(query);
            }
        }

    }

    public static SPListItemCollection PublicCompany = GetPhoneNumbers(Models.CAMLQueryBuilder.Public);
    public static SPListItemCollection AllCompany = GetPhoneNumbers(Models.CAMLQueryBuilder.All);
    public static SPListItemCollection OfficePublicCompany = GetPhoneNumbers(Models.CAMLQueryBuilder.PublicOffice);

}
```

Method `GetPhoneNumbers` is taking string from `CAMLQueryBuilder` class as parameter and returns `SPListItemCollection` which is later passed as parameter to `GetEmployeeInfo` method.

Later I've found that methods like `GetPhoneNumbers` should be written inside `SharePointConnector` class , and shouldn't return `SPListItemCollection` ,instead of that I should write another class and `GetPhoneNumbers` is going to return that type instead .

Is there any idea how can I do that ? If you have any suggestion or advice on rewriting any part of code according to you knowledge of Repository Pattern please fill free to answer my question.
Thank you.